# How to fill the gridView layout with 100 cell?

Tags: java, android

I use gridview to display 100 number random (from 1 to 100).

```
grv_adapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.gridview_item,li_numbers);
gridView.setAdapter(grv_adapter);
```

the list **li_numbers** store 100 number.

and this is result.
[image]

I want  the remaining space is filled , I tried some ways by set height and width for each cell but the result still not good.

There are 2 ways I want :

1. 100 these cell should auto "resize" to fill remaining space
2. list number can add more number (ex : 101, 102... ) to fill remaining space.

My expect reuslt look like this image 
[image]

Please give me a help !

Comment: add five more objects in li_numbers  and check.

Comment: @user3676184 this screen need add five numbers but how about others screen size ? It is different for kinds of screen

Comment: ok post xml file code for gridview

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the screen height and width first, then divided by no of rows and columns you want. Once you get these numbers, you can set these to your cell width and height.

Comment: You might want to show some codes so that people can look and help.